# Safari minimize button is disabled

Tags: macos, osx-lion, safari, window-manager

I have a MacBook Pro with Mac OS X version 10.7.5. Safari's minimize button (the one with a '-' in it in left top corner) is disabled (turned gray) and now either I have to keep Safari on the desktop all the time or close the page and reopen it. I have updated Safari and still the problem has not been solved. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using third party software that's dealing with window management? Is only Safari affected? Since when does this issue occur? Is there anything interesting shown in Console.app? Does it occur for other user accounts (create some if you don't have any)?

Comment: It has happened since a month ago. I use basic Safari. The only problem I have on machine right now is that after installing Adope flash player, I keep getting some error messages in pages which include videos, as I am not proficient in dealing with computer issues, I push dismiss all and the page opens with no problem.  Do you think this is the culprit?

Comment: I have this problem with Safari only. I have not done anything to my window management. BTW, I've just started using multiple desktops by connecting a monitor to my laptop, and I think this issue with safari started sometime after this.

Comment: @Solmaz Have you any plug-ins activated? See under **Preferences** > **Extensions**.

Comment: @NSAddict In my Preferences there is not Extensions. However, theres "others". As I mentioned above I kept getting error messages when I watch videos which use Adope Flash player. My problem seems to be solved now, this is what I did. In 'system Preferences" I clicked on 'Flash Player", in the "storage" I clicked on "delete all ..." and then chose the  first option, "delete all site data and setting", and then clicked ok. This seems to solve my problem. Can someone explain what was going on? Thank you NSAddict, for putting me in the right path.

Answer (score -1):

I, too, had the aforementioned problem. After trial and error, I was able to solve the mystery of the missing yellow, minimize circle.

I accidentally pressed the green circle which removed the toolbar surrounding the white space in the window (where the red, yellow and green buttons reside in the upper left hand corner)thus enlarging the white space. When I pressed the green circle again, the window was minimized and the yellow circle reappeared! Yay!

Comment: The original poster clearly states that it “turned gray” which means this is not a full-screen mode issue but rather something else.